# How to show seconds in Windows 10 UWP TimePicker control?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, timepicker, windows-10-universal

I am currently working in Windows 10 and want to create a countdown timer similar to [Count Down Timer](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/building-a-windows-phone-countdown-timer-app-step-by-step). In this sample, they have used Coding4Fun Toolkit and when I added this through Nuget Package Manager it didn't have TimeSpanPicker control so I tried with Time Picker and it works perfectly fine. The only issue is it is showing only hours and minutes and not seconds. Is there any way we can add seconds section directly or by editing TimePicker template or any third party available?

Please suggest whether it is possible or not?

Comment: Please refer this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol/ to implement looping itempanel

Comment: There is no sample which shows adding sections in this url.

Comment: There is a downloadable zip at the end. https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/41/15/61/ItemsTemplatePanel.zip

Comment: its same mentioned in sample :-(

Comment: Yup. I have seen the code. What i said is you can use LoopItemsPanel.cs  create your own TimePicker. In that case you have to use 3 listbox  each uses LoopItemsPanel as ItemsPanel(for hour,min,sec)

Comment: Ok, I will try this, but then I may need to add all the parameters also like TimePicker.Time,TimeChanged event,etc

Comment: You can use selection changed event.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt299156.aspx Are you aware what is the period in this template? Default template uses 3 text blocks.

Comment: I guess its for AM/PM,https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.aspx

Comment: ok if I create one more TextBlock in this template then I think it should work but I am not sure from where the values come from for hours and minutes, so using that I can add for seconds also.

Comment: Yes. I guess its not possible to acheive what you want by just  editing the template. Because by tapping third textbox you need to open flyout to select the seconds right?

Comment: Right now when I tap on it, both hr and minute flyout open by default.I just want to use it for display so it displayed my countdown in decreasing order.

Comment: You dont want second flyouts then? What i thought is you want 3 flyouts for hr,min,sec

Comment: Why not instead of using TimePicker Show your countdown timer show textblocks with values updating on every tick?

Comment: OP wants flyouts like TimePicker flyout to select the date,then start countdown

Comment: Is it possible to use dispatcher timer and based on its value update Textblock?? But I am not sure whether it will show HR, min and second

Comment: Yes I understand.That was a suggestion to @KinjanBhavsar. He could first show the TimePicker then after user selects time collapse its visibility and replace it with textblocks which would show the countdown. Else OP will have to create custom layout or extend current timePicker. Yes you will have to use dispatcherTimer and on its ticks you will have to update the UI.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. Actually my requirement is just to show countdown to user not allow him to change its time, time is already saved locally and I am deducting current time from it and want to show timer

Comment: OK. Then you don't want TimePicker. You just have to use textbox and timer to update

Comment: Yes @Archana Add your comment as answer. Once I achieve my requirement I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed use `TextBlock` instead of TimePicker,since you don't want user to edit the timer value.  Use `DispatcherTimer` class to implement countdown. you may have to use `Dispatcher.RunAsync` method to update the UI thread.